# Javascript : Return Unmatched value from multidimensional arrays that contains object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I have two multidimensional arrays that each of them contain some objects(key/value) I want loop throw object values to find unmatched value if found record the object with unmatched value I tried but I didn't get a result any help please in pure Javascript or Jquery or any other frameworks 
the bellow is my code

```
    var firstarry=[{'name':'alex','age':22,'numbersOne':['111','222','333','444','555'],'location':'iq'},{'name':'jan','age':33,'numbersOne':['999','111','222','333','444'],'location':'in'}];
    var secondarray=[{'name':'aga','age':12,'numbersTwo':['111','222','333','444'],'location':'usa'},{'name':'jan','age':35,'numbersTwo':['111','222','333','444'],'location':'uk'}];
    var un_mached_rows=[]; var tmp_recorder={};
    secondarray.forEach(function(secondarrayElements){
    if(secondarrayElements.hasOwnProperty('numbersTwo'))
        secondarrayElements.numbersTwo.forEach(function(numberoneElements){
            firstarry.forEach(function(firstarryElements){
                if(firstarryElements.hasOwnProperty('numbersOne')){
                    firstarryElements.numbersOne.forEach(function(numbersOneElements){
                        if(secondarrayElements.numbersTwo.indexOf(numbersOneElements)===-1)
                        {
                         tmp_recorder.name = firstarryElements.name;
                          tmp_recorder.age = firstarryElements.age;
                          tmp_recorder.location = firstarryElements.location;
                          tmp_recorder.numbers = numberOneElements;
                          un_mached_rows.push(tmp_recorder);
                          tmp_recorder;  
                        }

                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
    conslole.log(un_mached_rows);
```

I loop should return the array that contain two objects like`un_mached_rows=[{'name':'alex','age':22,'numbers':'555','location':'iq'},{'name':'jan','age':33,'numbers':'999','location':'in'}]`

but it doesn't work properly really I'm confused please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    var firstarry=[
    {
     'name':'alex',
     'age':22,
     'numbersOne':['111','222','333','444','555'],
     'location':'iq'
    },{
     'name':'jan',
     'age':33,
     'numbersOne':['999','111','222','333','444'],
     'location':'in'
     }
    ];
    var secondarray=[
    {
     'name':'aga',
     'age':12,
     'numbersTwo':['111','222','333','444'],
     'location':'usa'
     },{
      'name':'jan',
      'age':35,
      'numbersTwo':['111','222','333','444'],
      'location':'uk'
      }
    ];


    var un_mached=[];

    for(var seckey in secondarray){
       var numbersTwo=secondarray[seckey].numbersTwo;
       for(var firkey in firstarry){
          numbersOne=firstarry[firkey].numbersOne;;
              for(var nokey in numbersOne){
                var numbersOne_el=numbersOne[nokey];
                if($.inArray(numbersOne_el, numbersTwo) === -1) {
                 delete firstarry[firkey].numbersOne;
                 firstarry[firkey].numbers=numbersOne_el;
                    un_mached.push(firstarry[firkey]);
                    delete firstarry[firkey];
                }
              }

       }
    }

    console.log(un_mached);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```